# How to create a KStream with a collection object as value?

Tags: java-8, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am working on Spring cloud stream kafka streams binder. In my consumer bean method, I want to return KStream with List of String as value -

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<Object, String>, KStream<String, List<String>>> method() {
        return input -> {
        /* business logic */
        return KStream<String, List<String>>;
        };
}
```

Is it possible to have a KStream with collection as its value? If so can anyone explain how to create it ?

Answer (score 1):

For this case, you could call `mapValues()`:

```java
return input -> {
    return input.mapValues(v -> {
        List<String> list = new LinkedList(); // or any other list implementation
        list.add(v); // or any other logic
        return list;
    }
};
```